# How to sync core data with Dropbox

Tags: ios, core-data, dropbox, xcode4.2

I am developing a finance based application in which I need to add dropbox sync feature.  For every entries I am adding/editing/deleting in the application, the changes should be applied to the data in the Drop Box.  For this, I searched and found [delta](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#delta) from which we can find the differences between the local DB and Drop Box DB and sync differences with the old one.

My doubt is in what format should I need to keep the core data in the Drop Box?
Whether the [delta](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#delta) is enough for syncing the data?

Comment: you need to call /delta if you are creating the same structure of folders and files to match the server. Core Data can be represented in an xml file, and you just need to use the get and put methods to keep it synced.

Comment: Is it possible to apply only the changes to the drop box data or to overwrite the entire data in the Drop Box?

Comment: u can call delta which will probably return for u the files that have changed. and then u overwrite only those files